# Apache Beam - fixed window with default trigger producing early results

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to understand windowing and triggers. I have created a streaming pipeline that runs on DirectRunner. The pipeline is as follows:

- Reading data from pub sub
- Parsing the data
- Assigning timestamps
- Windowing using `FixedWindows()` of 100 seconds
- Grouping the elements in that window
- Printing the output(with start and end of window)
- Finally, writing to another pub sub topic

Data

```
Counts, Unix_Timestamp
1, 1553578200
2, 1553578201
3, 1553578202
4, 1553578203
...
```

Beam Pipeline

```
def encode_byte_string(element):
  #element = ', '.join(element)
  #count = str(count)
  element = str(element)
  print element
  return element.encode('utf-8')

def custom_timestamp(message):
  data, time_stamp = message.split(',')
  # assuming that message is already parsed JSON (dict)
  return beam.window.TimestampedValue(data, int(time_stamp))

class BuildRecordFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
    window_start = window.start
    window_end = window.end
    return [element + (window_start,) + (window_end,)]


pubsub_data = (
                p 
                | 'Read from pub sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription= input_subscription)
                | 'Remove extra chars' >> beam.Map(lambda data: (data.rstrip().lstrip()))
                | 'CustomTimestamp' >> beam.Map(custom_timestamp)
                | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(100))
                | 'Form Key Value pair' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (1, int(x)))
                | 'Sum values' >> beam.GroupByKey()
                | 'AddWindowEndTimestamp' >> beam.ParDo(BuildRecordFn())
                | 'Encode to byte string' >> beam.Map(encode_byte_string)
                | 'Write to pub sub' >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(output_topic)
              )


result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

According to the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#event-time-triggers)

> The default trigger for a PCollection is based on event time, and
>   emits the results of the window when the Beam’s watermark passes the
>   end of the window, and then fires each time late data arrives.

I am expecting that I should get result something like

```
(1, [1,2,3,4, ..., 99], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [99,100,101,102, ..., 199], Timestamp(1553578300), Timestamp(1553578400))
```

However, when I run this pipeline, I am getting early results before even passing end of the window

```
(1, [11], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [12, 16, 15], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [19, 18, 8, 10, 23, 21, 1, 7, 9, 13], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [5, 6, 14, 17, 20, 22], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [33], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [3], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [24, 28, 29, 37, 39, 43], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [2, 4], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [48], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [25, 31, 34, 36, 38, 40, 46, 49, 51], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [26, 27, 30, 32, 41, 42, 45, 47], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [44, 52], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
(1, [35, 50], Timestamp(1553578200), Timestamp(1553578300))
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the case of late data that described in here. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data

One way to mitigate this kind of issue is adding some kind of "delay" using `withAllowedLateness`. But, the function, seems only available right now in Java SDK.

One other way, probably using `AfterWatermark` trigger. But, I haven't tried it yet. So, take it with pinch of salt.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#event-time-triggers) `AfterWatermark` is event-time trigger and also the default trigger. So, if I specify the trigger or not, we are working with `AfterWatermark`. Moreover, the issue is not of late data, I haven't even finished streaming input for that window and it starts emitting results.

Comment: isn't it simply because the fixed window is in seconds, not in number of items?

Comment: hmmm I'll probably need to re-test this again to ensure what I had in mind. But, I believe that's what OP wants right? to have a window in seconds instead of number of items